# DriverManager - getConnection does not catch SQLException for wrong URL

Tags: java, database

```
public Database(String dbname) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    _conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbname+".db");
    _sta = _conn.createStatement();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Database db;

    try {
        db = new Database("wrongurl");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException  i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to catch an SQLException when the `DriverManager.getConnection` URL is wrong. Nevertheless my code never reach the `catch (SQL Exception e)` statement even when the URL given to `Database` constructor is wrong.

Did I misunderstand the documentation? If so, how do I capture a wrong url?

Comment: You're doing it. SQLException will occur here if wrongurl.db doesn't exist. Did you actually run this exact code?

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yes I do and SQLException does not occur with a wrong url

Comment: so what does happen?  You either get some other exception (if so, update your question and include it), or you have the value that your call to getConnection returned. If it's null, update your question and say that. If it's not null, interact with it, what happens? Run query `SELECT 1;` for example.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It returns a `Connection` object, running `SELECT 1` does not throw any error but running query on a table, which doesn't exist since the database name is wrong, throw an error: `[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: tablename)`

Comment: Okay, so, it's a valid URL, and it opens a new database named 'wrongurl'. Nothing wrong about it.